# Get properties by QID?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I can get item and its properties by label:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
  (SAMPLE(?DR) as ?DR) (SAMPLE(?article)as ?article)
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item ?label "Einstein"@en
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P569 ?DR .}
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P570 ?RIP .}
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P18 ?image .}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
```

See on [Wikidata Query Services](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%0A%20%20%20%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FDR%29%20as%20%3FDR%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Farticle%29as%20%3Farticle%29%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Einstein%22%40en%20%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FDR%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP570%20%3FRIP%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription).

How can I do the same using QID instead label?

Comment: What is QID? Is it the URI of Albert Einstein? If so, simply replace the variabale `?item` with it.

Comment: in this case QID = Q937, replacing ?item doesn't work

Comment: You have to use full URIs or prefixed ones in SPARQL. Just Q937 is not a URI, this would be http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q937 . And then you can  remove the first two triple patterns. See my answer below.

Comment: @AKSW, your answer below?

Comment: Sorry, I had to format it. Now it's there

Comment: Note, that you have to add the other variables in the SELECT part as well and according to the official SPARQL standard, it's not allowed to reassign a variable like you did with `(sample(?DR) as ?DR)`. That's why I renamed it to `?DRSample`. Just to avoid confusion when you read the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the URI instead of the variable `?item` will get the information based on the entity Albert Einstein:

```
PREFIX  schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX  bd:   <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX  wdt:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX  wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription (SAMPLE(?DR) AS ?DRSample) (SAMPLE(?article) AS ?articleSample)
WHERE
  { ?article  schema:about       ?item ;
              schema:inLanguage  "en" ;
              schema:isPartOf    <https://en.wikipedia.org/>
    FILTER ( ?item = <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q937> )
    OPTIONAL
      { ?item  wdt:P569  ?DR }
    OPTIONAL
      { ?item  wdt:P570  ?RIP }
    OPTIONAL
      { ?item  wdt:P18  ?image }
    SERVICE wikibase:label
      { bd:serviceParam
                  wikibase:language  "en"
      }
  }
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
```

Comment: your answer can be applied to my other question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10334/get-items-properties-know-qid

Answer (score 5):

You can utilize the already known QID by using `BIND`:

```
BIND(wd:Q937 AS ?item).
...
```

Comment: yes, it's working. Should I use BIND or FILTER? Which is better?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the QID of the entity you are looking for and simply look for its properties and labels, you're better off using the [Wikidata API `wbgetentities` module](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities)

In A. Einstein ([Q937](https://wikidata.org/entity/Q937)) case, that would give the following API call: 
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q937&format=json

Comment: but can I use SPARQL?

Comment: you could, doing something like `wd:Q937 ?property ?value` ([try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fproperty%20%3FpropertyLabel%20%3Fvalue%20%3FvalueLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ937%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)) but that would be a mess to parse, with no benefice I'm aware of.

Comment: this json is very big. How I can get only required information, for example: label, description, birthday, link to image and wikipedia link?

Comment: you can pick which information among `info|sitelinks|aliases|labels|descriptions|claims|datatype` you want, using the `props` parameter. Ex: [with only sitelinks and descriptions](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q937&format=json&props=sitelinks|descriptions)

Comment: then, to simplify claims, if by any chance you are working in javascript, I can recommend [wikidata-sdk](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-sdk)'s [`simplifyClaims`](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-sdk#simplify-claims-results) parsing functions (a library I wrote)

Comment: looks interesting, I'll look at it