# Wikidata Query Service: how do I search by item?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am using the Wikidata Query Service (https://query.wikidata.org) to get details about movies and Tv shows.

I know I can query for genre of all items that are instance of film (query below) but I want to look for just specific movies.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?genreLabel
WHERE
{
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?item wdt:P136 ?genre
    }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
} LIMIT 10
```

I have a list of the Wikidata item numbers (Q###) for movies and Tv shows that I want to get properties about. I need to query these specific films or TV shows. For example, if I know that Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope is Q17738 in Wikidata, how can I query for specific properties of it?

Answer (score 7):

There are (at least) two ways of specifying multiple items in SPARQL.

`FILTER (?item IN (...list...))`: [SPARQL definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in)

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?genreLabel
WHERE
{
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .

    FILTER (?item IN (wd:Q17738, wd:Q181795))

    OPTIONAL {
        ?item wdt:P136 ?genre
    }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language  
                                "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
} LIMIT 10
```

`VALUES ?item { ...list... }`: [SPARQL definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data)

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?genreLabel
WHERE
{
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .

    VALUES ?item { wd:Q17738 wd:Q181795 }

    OPTIONAL {
        ?item wdt:P136 ?genre
    }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language  
                                "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
} LIMIT 10
```

The difference is that `IN` is simply a function: is argument in this list?

`VALUES` is a way to pass in data to a query. Although we used the simple form you can provide full, tabular data:

```
VALUES (?x ?y) {
   (:uri1 1)
   (:uri2 UNDEF)
}
```

The syntax has a special case for one variable, so I didn't have to write `VALUES ?item { (wd:Q17738) (wd:Q181795) }`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get properties using QID, see [answer to my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536933/240564), using filtering by URI.

Example for your item Q17738:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription (SAMPLE(?article) AS ?articleSample)
WHERE
  { ?article  schema:about       ?item ;
              schema:inLanguage  "en" ;
              schema:isPartOf    <https://en.wikipedia.org/>
    FILTER ( ?item = <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q17738> )    
    SERVICE wikibase:label
      { bd:serviceParam
                  wikibase:language  "en"
      }
  }
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
```

See this [query in WikiData](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Farticle%29%20AS%20%3FarticleSample%29%0AWHERE%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Farticle%20%20schema%3Aabout%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%20%22en%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%20%20%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20%3Fitem%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ17738%3E%20%29%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%20%22en%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription).

See also [answer on Open Data site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10406/3286).

Answer (score 1):

You could get properties about a given entity from the SPARQL endpoint, but you are probably better off querying the [`wbgetentities`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities) Wikidata API module.

Ex: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q17738&languages=en|de|fr&format=json

See also: [Getting readable results from Wikidata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31290824/3324977)